# describing the random variable $Y_n$ and finding an example

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given a probabality space  $(\Omega_n, \mathscr{A}_n, P_n)$ with  $\Omega_n=[0, \infty)^n$for  $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathscr{A}_n=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap \mathscr{P(\Omega_n)}$, and the density $f(x_1,...,x_n)=\lambda^nexp(-\lambda(x_1+...+x_n))$. For the random variable $X_k:\Omega_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $X_k(x_1,...,x_n)=x_k$ where $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$, we've got the probabality $\mathbb{P}(X_k \in (a,b))=\int_a^b\lambda exp(-\lambda x)dx$.
Now I've got to describe the distribution of the random variable $Y_n:\Omega_n \rightarrow \{0,...,n\}=max(k:\sum_{i=1}^kx_i<1)$ and compare both of them ($X_k$ and$Y_n$) to a stochastic model in real life. I just don't know how I can imagine $Y_n$ myself. What is the main difference between $X_k$ and $Y_n$? Maybe someone knows an example that fits in here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\P{\operatorname{\mathbb P}}$Ah, so, basically then: $(X_j)_{1\leq j\leq n}$ is a sequence of $n$ independent and indentically *somehow* distributed, non-negative, random variables, with *some* parameter $\lambda$.   Therefore  $Y_n$ is the index just before the partial sum of the sequence meets or exceeds $1$.

Let us define that partial sum as $Z_k := \sum_{j=1}^k X_j$.   So we have that $Y_n = \max\{k:Z_k<1\}$ .

Identify the probability distribution for each partial sum, $Z_k$.   Then use this to find the *probability mass function* for $Y_n$.

- Assume $Y_n=0$ if $X_1\geq 1$.   That is the very first term from the sequence exceeds $1$.
- Likewise $Y_n=n$ exactly when $Z_n<1$. That is when the sum for the entire sequence does not exceed 1.
- Otherwise, $Y_n = k$, for any $k:1\leq k<n$, exactly when $Z_k<1$ and $Z_{k+1}\geqslant 1$.   These terms are dependent.   However $Z_k$ and $X_{k+1}$ are independent; and $Z_{k+1}=Z_k+X_{k+1}$ by definition.

$$\P(Y_n =  k) ~=~\begin{cases}\P(X_1\geqslant 1) &:& k=0 \\ \P(Z_n<1) &:& k=n\\ \P(1 - X_{k+1} \leqslant Z_k < 1) & :& k\in\Bbb N, 1\leq k< n \\ 0 &:& k\notin\Bbb N\end{cases}$$